# Laravel Many To Many leftover id's to delete

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Currently I'm having 3 models in **Eloquent** on **Laravel 5.5**

**Product**

**Product_Category**

**Category**

---

Let's say I have some records in all of these models.
 Current state of Product_Category will be like this:

```
id | category_id | product_id
-----------------------------
5  | 2           | 2
6  | 3           | 3
7  | 4           | 1
```

**Now I will run the following function to update my records with Eloquent:**

```
public function updateObject($request, $id){
    $model = Product_Category::find($id);
    foreach($request->except('_token', 'categories') as $key=>$value){
        $model->setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
    $model->save();
    $model->id;

    foreach($request->only('categories') as $key=>$value){
        foreach($value as $category) {
            $product_category = Product_Category::where(['category_id' => $category["id"], 'product_id' => $model->id])->first();
            if($product_category == null) {
                $product_category = new Product_Category();
                $product_category->category_id = $category["id"];
                $product_category->product_id = $model->id;
            } else {
                $product_category->category_id = $category["id"];
                $product_category->product_id = $model->id;
            }
            $product_category->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**This function will work fine if:**

- You're adding new categories to the table
- You're editing existing categories for another value

---

**This function will not work if:**

- You're either not adding or editing but removing a category from the array

---

**My Issue**: when I edit categories from the table Product_Category I will keep old listed ID's from before if I have less categories than before but these need to be removed.

---

**My Question: How can I resolve this issue? So that the table Product_Category will always update with only the latest id's from the array**

I've already thought about a delete before executing the function but not sure if this is the "Eloquent way"

Comment: Can you elaborate the relation between `categories` & `products` and how they are stored in `product_category`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make use of Laravel Sync method.

```
foreach($request->only('categories') as $key=>$value) {
    $sync_data = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++) {
        $sync_data[$value[$i]["id"]] = ["product_id" => $model->id];
    }
    $model->categories()->sync($sync_data);
}
```

This will delete all unused records from the Product_Category table. And edit the corresponding records.

Answer (score 1):

The eloquent way is detaching records as described here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

```
$user->roles()->detach($roleId);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for. Trying to find a code specific solution now.

Comment: I'm looking into `sync([])` now

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the above structure, it seems the relationship is many to many between category & products.

The proper Eloquent structure will be:

#### Category model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->using(Product_Category::class);
}
```

#### Product model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->using(Product_Category::class);
}
```

#### Product_Category model

Following code should be written in the `Product_Category` model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Product_Category extends Pivot
{
//
}
```